# Как можно расположить картинку на экране через Python?

Tags: python

Мне надо расположить png картинку в определенной точке экрана. Важно, чтобы у нее был прозрачный фон, как и у самого .png файла. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Ну берите любой `GUI` фреймворк и делайте. В консоли же так не получится. `PyQt`, `Tkinter`, `Kivy`, `PyGame`, ...